# TypeError: Cannot set property '#<Object>' of undefined while swapping array element in javascript in python style

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to implement selection sort in javascript.

```js
let array = require('./../../utility/array').array;
const printJustValues = require('./../../utility/printArray');

const selectionsort = (array) => {    
    let minimum;
    for(let i = 0;i < array.length; i++) {
        minimum = i;
        for(let j = i; j < array.length; j++) {            
            if(array[j].nested.value < array[minimum].nested.value) {                
                minimum = j;
            }
        }
        
        [ array[minimum], array[i] ] = [ array[i], array[minimum] ];
        
        // let temp = array[i];
        // array[i] = array[minimum];
        // array[minimum] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

let result = selectionsort(array);
printJustValues(result);
```

While swapping elements, when I try to do it python style, it throws me error like:

```js
TypeError: Cannot set property '#<Object>' of undefined
    at selectionsort (/Users/mihirima/Documents/github/Algorithms-and-Data-Structures/algorithms/sorting/selectionsort/selectionsort.js:16:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mihirima/Documents/github/Algorithms-and-Data-Structures/algorithms/sorting/selectionsort/selectionsort.js:25:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Can anyone give me an explanation why it is happening? thanks.

Comment: What environment are you using? Are you sure it supports destructuring assignment? Your code works fine in Node 7.4.0.

Comment: I am using node 8.9.1

Comment: The error is being thrown at this line:
[ array[minimum], array[i] ] = [ array[i], array[minimum] ];

Comment: I've tried your example in node8.7.0 using a structure like [{nested: {value: ...}}, ...] and it works. You did not even need to return the array or assign it to result because your function changes the array in place.

Comment: Thanks @betadeveloper, but can you give me any idea why getting this error message?

Comment: If you've already tried using the _temp_ variable and it  worked, then might be really just the js environment you were using to run. Try it in the browser or something like repl.it and see if it works.